How to show seconds for Angular Material Timepicker
I'm using Angular Material Timepicker but it only shows hours and minutes. I would like to display seconds as well.
https://material.angular.io/components/timepicker/overview
Is it possible?

I ended up using https://github.com/danielmoncada/date-time-picker instead.

The Angular Material Timepicker does not natively support displaying or selecting seconds. The standard Angular Material Timepicker only allows for the selection of hours and minutes.
You could still use a third party library.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
